# Adding data to array through loop php

Tags: php, associative-array, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem where I am getting data from database and need to put that in an array. The array is associative and I am not sure about this practice so I thought I should ask the community. Is this the correct way of adding data to array? The array is for the radio buttons that will be provided to the helper class in prestashop. The array structure is important. [This is the var_dump array structure which I have in $options_break2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw8iz.png).

```
                    $options_value = array();
                    $options = array();
                    for($z=0; $z<sizeof($options_break2); $z++)
                    {
                        $options_value = array_push($options_value,
                            array(
                            "id" => $options_break2[$z],
                            "name" => $options_break2[$z],
                            "label" => $options_break2[$z],
                            )
                        );
                    }
                    $options = array_push($options, $options_value);
```

What I want is that the array should contain something like:

```
         $example = array(
            array(
                'id_option' => 'some value',
                'name' => 'some value',
            ),
            array(
                'id_option' => 'some value',
                'name' => 'some value',
            ),
        );
```

Comment: If you want your sub-arrays to have keys of `id_option` and `name` then why are you setting `id`, `name` and `label` keys in your code?

Comment: this is just an example, they can be changed later, the array structure is important. that is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use `array_push` and `array()` if your PHP version is above 5.6, and you can improve your loop by using the foreach loop:

```
$options_value = [];

foreach ($options_break2 as $opt) {
    $options_value[] = [
      "id_option" => $opt, // some_value
      "name" => $opt // some_value
    ];
}

$options = $options_value; // you don't really need this
```

Comment: options_break has the following kind of data: type 1, type 2
can we use foreach for this data?

Comment: update your question with an example of the array structure

Comment: by using the above way I am getting an array inside an array and inside that array is a value. I can post the screenshot to this in my question if you want?

Comment: add an example of what you want to get, and a var_dump/print_r of options_break2

Comment: question updated, also I have added an image in which I have shown the array structure of what I am getting after using the loop you provided to me

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just corrected some issues on my side and now I am getting correct output finally. :D